# Clicking sound after changing struts. 2008 Ford Escape hybrid

Tags: suspension, hybrid, escape, struts, clicking

I have a 2008 Ford Escape hybrid. I recently changed out my old struts for brand new ones. After the new ones were installed, I hear a clicking sound when I accelerate and when I brake. There will be one click when I accelerate from a dead stop. Also a click when I slow down and stop. One click when I go and then another click when I stop. I can’t figure out where it’s coming from. All the bolts and nuts for the strut are tight and torqued correctly. Does this sound like a loose brake pad or something? If anyone has any advice please let me know! Thanks

Comment: Did you check ball joints and tie rods?

Comment: Tie rods ends were replaced last year. I looked at the lower ball joint on the right side which Is where I think the noise is coming from and it looks fine.

Comment: I'm ignoring the fact that struts were just changed because properly installed struts won't do this. The most common causes for these symptoms are cause from play in the suspension. Tie rods, ball joints, loose steering gear, possibly CV joints or most often u joints of it's a 4WD or AWD.

Comment: It’s a hybrid and is only front wheel drive. I think it probably is not the cv joint as I changed it on that side last year. How do I check to see if it’s any of the other things you listed? I’ve taken the wheels off multiple times to see if I can see anything that’s loose and I couldn’t see anything but I’m no expert….

Comment: when i turn the steering wheel while the car is not moving, sometimes there is a thump sound but not always... do you think this has anything to do with the clicking noise?

Comment: Could very well be related. With the engine off and parking brake on have someone turn the steering wheel back and forth from 11:00 to 1:00 fairly rapidly while you reach behind tire and hold onto tie rod end. You should feel no slop or clunking. Repeat for ball joints. This is a quick check. If you cannot find the problem this way, you might want to take it to a shop. Clunking and clicking is not good in suspension parts.

Comment: ok ill try that out. Thanks! I took off the wheel again yesterday and noticed that the inside brake pad was slightly loose.  I could move it slightly with my fingers.  Do you think maybe that is the problem? If it is, should i replace only the pads on that side (they are only about a year old), or pads on both sides in the front?

Comment: so I took the car to a shop.  The mechanic changed my lower control arms with brand new ones.  Still making the clicking noise.  He checked everything and couldn't figure out what the sound was.